# large JSON using request nodejs

Tags: json, node.js

I am having issues using the request module to post to an end point and I think it is because when I use JSON.parse is it using [object] in place of nested objects.

```
   { resource:
   { resourceType: 'newtestone',
     identifier: [ [Object] ],

     rules: [ [Object] ] } }
```

My post here:

```
    request.post({
        headers: {'content-type' : 'application/json'},
        url:     'https://' + username + ':' + password +     '@localhost:9000/newtestone',
        json:    newdata,
  }, function(error, response, body){
    console.log(body);
  });
```

The post is failing so I'm wondering how I can remove those [Object] and display the entire JSON.
I've tried stringify and it doesn't work.

EDIT: never mind problem was with my JSON object.

Comment: This is just the output of the `toString()` method. You might want to `JSON.stringify` your data object before posting it.

Answer (score 0):

By default the entire object is not displayed in the console, if you want to display it simply use console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)) or use util.inspect(obj,{depth:null})

```
 var a = {e:1,b:2,c:{d:{e:4,f:{sdfd:5,trtr:{h:55}}}}};
 console.log(a); // { e: 1, b: 2, c: { d: { e: 4, f: [Object] } } }

 console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
 // {"e":1,"b":2,"c":{"d":{"e":4,"f":{"b":5,"a":{"h":55}}}}}

 console.log(util.inspect(a,{depth:null}));
 // { e: 1, b: 2, c: { d: { e: 4, f: { b: 5, a: { h: 55 } } } } }
```

when using {json:{}} in request you don't need the content-type headers

What is displayed in error, or response.statusCode ?